# How to convert block of html to an image (e.g. jpg) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, image, rendering

I would like to convert html (for example, a table) to an image and save it as a .jpg file. And, if that table is displayed within a web page along with other elements, I only want to get that specific table and save it as an image.

Is this possible using asp.net?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a HTML Control (Div or Table) to an image using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972739/convert-a-html-control-div-or-table-to-an-image-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a rendering issue and completely depends upon what browser rendering your HTML.

But this the closest thing I could get you using `GDI+` and `WebBrowser` control from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx).

Let me know whether it helped you or not!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

We have used `http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/`  to convert HTML to image. You can try it out. It is available for FREE.

or

ref

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972739/convert-a-html-control-div-or-table-to-an-image-using-c
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%@ Page Language="c#"%> 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Imaging" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Drawing2D" %> 

<script runat="server"> 
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {   
Bitmap bmp= new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["i"]));   
Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(bmp);   
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias ;   
g.DrawString(Request.QueryString["t"],    
new Font("verdana",12),SystemBrushes.WindowText, 1, 1);   
Response.ContentType="image/jpeg";   
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, bmp.RawFormat) ; } 
</script>
```