# convert DIV contents to Image in C# or JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have a DIV container which has some text, background-image, image. I need to convert that whole DIV contents into image and save into local folder.
Please guide me how to convert Div contents to Image using JavaScript or C#.
I have searched in Google, but not getting correct result. give some source code please.. help me guys.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316564/taking-screenshot-of-a-webpage-programmatically.

Comment: @rt2800 that answer is for capturing whole webpage, he is looking for particular Div to capture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't want to conver whole HTML page but a part of html, See the answer given by p.campbell in the following link for the perfect solution.

[Convert a HTML Control (Div or Table) to an image using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972739/convert-a-html-control-div-or-table-to-an-image-using-c-sharp)

Other answers maybe providing capturing whole html web page to image. If you find the p.campbell's answer hard to implement , create an html page in the website with only Div content and capture it to image by given other answers.

Comment: sorry Imran Rizvi .. Im not clear how it works. will u please elaborate me with source code??

Comment: it takes screenshot for the URL. I want only a div contents to Image.

Comment: did you see the second answer of p.campbell?

Comment: Don't bother using C# - you can do this with JavaScript in a much more efficient manner.

Answer (score 2):

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ is what you're looking for. Usage:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Example of capturing the div</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pictureMe"><p>Try this out on JSFiddle right now.</p></div>
    <script src="js/html2canvas.js" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            html2canvas(document.getElementByID("pictureMe"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            /* What you want to do with the screenshot goes here */
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fG4fY/ is now available.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ConvertToCanvas(btnExporttoimage) {
            html2canvas($("#ContentInfo")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
                var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("[id*=hdnImageData]").val(base64);
                __doPostBack(btnExporttoimage.name, "");
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="ContentInfo" runat="server" style="width: 600px; background-color: White;
        padding: 5px; height: 600px;">
        <u>Student Info</u>
        <br />
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Country
                </td>
                <td class="style1">
                    Roll.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Ranjit
                </td>
                <td>
                    India
                </td>
                <td class="style1">
                    2345
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Soumya
                </td>
                <td>
                    India
                </td>
                <td class="style1">
                    5678
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    3
                </td>
                <td>
                    Tapan
                </td>
                <td>
                    Srilanka
                </td>
                <td class="style1">
                    7890
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    4
                </td>
                <td>
                    Suresh
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bhutan
                </td>
                <td class="style1">
                    4345
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnImageData" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnExporttoimage" Text="Export to Image" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
        OnClientClick="return ConvertToCanvas(this)" OnClick="btnExporttoimage_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
  /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}

protected void btnExporttoimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string base64 = Request.Form[hdnImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
    byte[] IMGbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    ///////////-------FOLLOWING CODE IS TO CONVERT IMAGE TO BINARY AND TO DEFAULT DOWNLOAD PATH--------////////////////////  
    //Response.Clear();
    //Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","canvas.png"));
    //Response.Buffer = true;
    //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    //Response.BinaryWrite(IMGbytes);
    //Response.End();


    ///////////-------FOLLOWING CODE IS TO CONVERT IMAGE TO BINARY AND TO DESIRE DOWNLOAD PATH--------////////////////////  
    MemoryStream msImage = new MemoryStream(IMGbytes, 0, IMGbytes.Length);
    msImage.Write(IMGbytes, 0, IMGbytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image imageTosave = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(msImage, true);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CanvasImages/"), "canvas.png");
    imageTosave.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .labans {
            /*  color:#990000;*/
            color: #336600;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 600;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .labans1 {
            /*  color:#990000;*/
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 600;
        }



        .divsection {
            border: 1px solid #DDD;
            padding: 8px 15px;
            spacing: 2px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: #EEEEEE 0.4em 0.0em 0.2em;
            background-image: url(../Images/Front.jpg);
            height: 15cm;
            width: 9.5cm;
            background-size: 358px;
            background-position: center top;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            object-fit: fill;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
    <!--ForExport data in iamge -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ConvertToImage(btnExport) {
            html2canvas($("#dvContent")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
                var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
                __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <!--ForExport data in iamge -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../data/assets/js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="row" id="divhiddenInfo" runat="server" style="display: none">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="lblCode" runat="server" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" Text="Download Front" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
            OnClick="DownloadImage" OnClientClick="return ConvertToImage(this)" />

        <div id="dvContent" class="divsection">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfImageData" runat="server" />
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>

                    <td valign="Right">
                        <table width="88%">

                            <tr>
                                <td class="style43">
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="155px" Width="129px" ImageAlign="Right" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDegs" runat="server" CssClass="labans"></asp:Label>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" CssClass="labans"></asp:Label>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <asp:Label ID="lbllocation" runat="server" CssClass="labans"></asp:Label>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>



            </table>

        </div>

    </form>
</body>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


protected void DownloadImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Front.jpeg");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```