# what is the easy way to convert simple html to bitmap/image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, rendering

In my project, i has many simple html text in database eg.

```
<ul>this is apple</ul>
<ul>this is orange</ul>
<p>I want to <u>eat</u> apple</p>
hello <i>mr</i> orange
```

In my project, I have a server and a client. the server will read the html text from database, the client is a web client, it must get the html text in form of Image object to display it.(I have my own reason not to display html text directly in DOM......), anyway the client must display everything in the form of image.

Now I think 2 approach to solve this problem.
the first one , server convert 'html text' into image (eg. base64 string) , then send it to client.
or .....
the second one, client get the 'html text' and convert it by javascript to javascript image object in the browser.

my server program is a dot net program.
my client is browser which can run html5, eg. chrome, firefox.

How can I do it?

Comment: Well the *easiest* way is to use a 3rd-party library, e.g. http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToImage.aspx

Comment: Have you tried either of the approaches you suggested in your post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a HTML Control (Div or Table) to an image using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972739/convert-a-html-control-div-or-table-to-an-image-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before using the js plugin [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
It's not perfect, but it works pretty good, and maybe it improved since I last used it.

If you want to do it on the server side, you can crawl the page with a headless browser like [phantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) and have it create a screenshot for you, but this will probably be more complicated to setup.

Comment: thanks, gilyb, long time ago I also have try the casperjs too. but all of them are not running in dot net. my server admin only allow me to run dot net program. on the other hand  , thanks your suggestions. but I found a more simple method on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: oh, thanks! I wasn't aware of that method. I'll look into it. I know that html2canvas has ways of dealing with external images as well, so you should look into it if you run into problems like that.